# What is the difference between, @Configuration and @Import

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I have three Spring Context Class.

I used to annotate them with `Configuration` individually.

But recently I tried with `Import` annotation in one of the context class, and import the other two classes. But If I did so, in one of my `RestController` annotated class, I will encounter the following error causing a failed start:

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle.
```

But this error never occurred when I annotated them three individually.

So What `@Import` actually do besides `@Configuration`?

I am using **Spring Boot 1.4.2**

Thanks.

Comment: Given Class A, B and C. A is importing B and C while B or C is importing A. you need to show us your class headers in order to get help with your specific problem.

Comment: They still should be annotated with `@Configuration` to indicate that they are configuration classes. (They ar treated very specially inside the framework). If you don't you will run in some sort of lite mode (see the reference guide) which gives them a completely different lifecycle and features.

Comment: @M.Deinum, after annotated the other two context class with `@Configuration`, this error did vanish. But what is the point to using `@Import`? since without it will also work. Does `@Import` guarantee the context beans loaded order?(loaded firstly if annotated with `@Import`?). Thanks

Comment: In a lot of cases people disable detection of `@Configuration` classes and want to be explicit about which ones to use aka `@Import`. Or if you use some 3rd party library and only want to scan your own packages and not others but still want to use that library.

Comment: I might understand, you mean there is a `Component-scan` stuff default in **Spring Boot** which has some overlay functionalities against `@Import`? But is this the cause for *forming a cycle* error?

Comment: No the cycle is due to you removing the `@Configuration` annotation. The fact that you use `@Import` doesn't mean you shouldn't annotate those classes with `@Configuration` anymore. That annotation is still needed!

Comment: Yes, Mister. I will go for some reference guide for more details. Could you please answer below, so I can upvote that? Thanks.